# Magento 2: Show subtotal without discount in Cart page

Tags: magento2, cart, discount, subtotal

In my custom module, I need to Display **subtotal** without **discount**`(subtotal - discount)` how can I achieve my needs? , any help appreciated.
   Thank you

Comment: Where you want to display that subtotal in your custom module?

Comment: in my summery section

Comment: In Magento, Order edit page in backend or frontend ?

Comment: in frontend , user cart (summery block below the discount)

Comment: You mean you want to change subtotal here ?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jqTlHoc-PH5M_bCiBqDBSEK9HjJNZsH4/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @KishanSavaliya sorry , actually i need subtotal before discount

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99910/discussion-between-kishan-savaliya-and-shafeel-sha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override **getValue()** function in this js in your module

> vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/summary/subtotal.js

In your custom module you can override that function as below...

> app/code/MageHelper/ShippingDiscount/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'MageHelper_ShippingDiscount',
    __DIR__
);
```

> app/code/MageHelper/ShippingDiscount/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="MageHelper_ShippingDiscount" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

> app/code/MageHelper/ShippingDiscount/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/subtotal': {
                'MageHelper_ShippingDiscount/js/view/checkout/summary/subtotal-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

> app/code/MageHelper/ShippingDiscount/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/summary/subtotal-mixin.js

```
define([
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function (Component, quote) {
    'use strict';

    var mixin = {
        getValue: function () {
            var price = 0;

            if (this.totals()) {
                price = this.totals().subtotal + this.totals().base_discount_amount;
            }

            return this.getFormattedPrice(price);
        }
    };

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend(mixin);
    };
});
```

**You can add your vendor and module name where I've added MageHelper and ShippingDiscount**

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: @shafeel-sha are you getting any issues ?

Comment: yes , not getting correct value , subtotal added with discount

Comment: I've added this **this.totals().subtotal + this.totals().base_discount_amount** because in base_discount_amount we will get amount with minus (-) sign. What exact issue you are getting there ?

Comment: After adding above code please clear your browser cache once and then try to check. that will work.

Comment: Thanks Brother its working now

Comment: What was causing there before ?

Comment: Great thing! My solution is helpful to you. :-)

Comment: yeah, actually my subtotal value taken  from tax excluding so, I'm using that function instead of getValue

Comment: Okay understood..

Comment: I'm on holidays. Will check after 2 days.